# How to set environment variables to different values when many tests are executing in parallel?

Tags: linux, qsub

My goal is to start a large number of tests in parallel and dump the coverage(`*.gcda` files) into different directories. I will be using "qsub". But, the problem is I should set different values for the same environment variable `GCOV_PREFIX` before running each test. I don't know if this will interfere with multiple tests running in parallel?

For example, I have test1, test2, test3, and I need to set environment variable GCOV_PREFIX = test1 before running test1, GCOV_PREFIX = test2 before running test2, and GCOV_PREFIX = test3 before running test3. 
So how do I do it with command "qsub", so the coverage files get dumped in different directories?

The final result needs be .gcda files inside respective test folders, like test1/.gcda, test2/.gcda etc.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

In SGE `qsub` command, you can set a variable list by `-v`, you can find more information in the [man page](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html).

Here is a python test script test.sh:

`python -c "import os;print os.getenv('GCOV_PREFIX')"`

Then you can submit test.sh by:
`qsub -v GCOV_PREFIX=TEST1 <another-options> test.sh`
The output will be written to test.sh.o file.

But if you have set the same variable in somewhere like `~/.bashrc` by:

`export GCOV_PREFIX=TEST4BASHRC`

The output will be **TEST4BASHRC**, maybe SGE will read the variable in the user definded config after parsing `-v` options of qsub.